# Past perfect vs. past simple

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Consider this scenario: my room is messy, I then clean it up. In a day, however, the room is utterly messy again. What should I think to myself?

> The room looks as though I **had not done** any cleaning up yesterday at all.

or

> The room looks as though I **did not do** any cleaning up yesterday at all.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think either to yourself and be fine, though they have different *nuances*.

Knowing that you *had* cleaned up, the first one is, pedantically, a little better.

The second one *could* have the connotations that you were "running on autopilot" yesterday and though you assumed you cleaned up normally, it looks like you didn't do it.

The first one would probably be better for a test, but if you just want to sound natural, either one's fine. (Or you could say, "It looks like I didn't clean up at all!")